# So much of living to do or So much living to do. Which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions

"So much of living to do" or "So much living to do". Which one is correct?

I was writing caption for my Instagram post. Wasn't sure which one is correct.

Comment: The second is correct!

Comment: It helps if you give the example of a whole sentence so that we can understand in which way you wish to use the phrase.